# How to solve: Xcode Archive upload failed with error 22421

Tags: ios, xcode, compiler-errors, upload

I tried everything but I cannot upload a build to iTunes anymore. It worked for over a year perfectly, but since I had to re-install macOS Sierra, I get this error and trying over and over again doesn't help.

I have the latest Xcode from the App Store and I can run the App on my developer phone, the app is actually already in the App Store, I can use the simulator, no build errors, but the moment I try to upload a new build I get the 22421 error without any detailed description.

Does anybody know how to solve this?

Comment: Have you tried cleaning the build folder? (hold down option while clicking on the Product > Clean menu item)

Comment: Yes I did. After searching for another half an hour I found a solution which worked for me:

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution (in Terminal) on the official developer forums:

```
cd ~  
mv .itmstransporter/ .old_itmstransporter/  
"/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Application Loader.app/Contents/itms/bin/iTMSTransporter"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try following solutions:
Use **Application Loader** to upload your app, as Xcode organizer can't upload file (rejects IPA) sometimes, without genuine reason and it's frequently occurring issue, with Xcode Organizer, that apple could not resolve permanently.

**Solution for error code: 22421**

> - Apple app upload server is not working properly (not in
>     connection or lost connection during file upload). Just wait and try
>     again later (may be after a day).
> - Fluctuation in your network
>     connection, during file upload.
> - You may not have added privacy
>     statements in your info.plist file.

[Cocoa Keys](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html): Here, is list of keys that you should consider to add in your info.plist file, if you have used that service in your application.

**Nowadays, you may also face, this error code: 90186 (with app loader)**

> - Outdated application loader can be reason of this error. Use [latest Xcode tool](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/xcode/id497799835?ls=1&mt=12) and use application loader from Xcode Tool.
> - Incorrect/invalid provisioning profile, associated with your build. Ensure, your have used correct provisioning profile (A provisioning
>     profile with **Distribution/Production** mode is require. A *Development mode* provisioning profile won't allow your to upload app on store.)

You can find latest Application Loader Tool from latest Xcode Tool: Xcode -> Open Developer Tool -> Application Loader

[image]